# How to import dumb.rdb file on redis and export it to mysql Database

Tags: mysql, csv, redis

RDB file of REDIS server that is imported from another server. I have installed the REDIS on my local machine and trying to import it in local REDIS server. mainly i want to store all REDIS data  mysql database. Is any direct process to import DUMB.RBD file to mysql database .Is it any other process by which i import the REDIS data into CSV format.any help will be vey useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer with Node js and Redis .

For Import i have used the following command After shut down the redis server

```
sudo cp /var/dump.rdb /home/etc/redis/dump.rdb
```

Parses the Redis data with Nodejs and connected it to mysql same time .

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host              : 'localhost',
port              : '3306',
database          : 'db',
user              : 'root',
password          : 'password',
insecureAuth      : true,
multipleStatements: true
});
var post  = {name: practice.name, practiceId: practice.id,type: practice.wid};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO  facilities SET ?', post, function(err, result) { });

                console.log(query.sql +';');
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis is schema free key-value NOSQL database. Here is no any build in solutions for move data from Redis to SQL database or CSV file. But you can write some code to do this themself:

1. Use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/SCAN) to get all keys in your Redis instance.
2. Get they values depends on key type (which can be determin with [TYPE](http://redis.io/commands/type)).
3. Write to SQL.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379> when entering scan 0
(error) ERR unknown command 'scan'
 I have existing 1.5 gb dump.rdb file .i  want to see data and import it to csv of json

Comment: SCAN command is supported only from version 2.8.0. You might be using older version of Redis. In that case u can use KEYS command.